# Why am i getting one weird plot in Tensorboard after running CNN Tensorflow example?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am trying to visualize the plots in TensorBoard after running the CNN for mnist dataset using the example in their website. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

I m getting "test accuracy", "training loss", "global_step/sec" plots. However, i am also getting a weird plot as shown in the image below
[enqueue_input/queue/enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queuefraction_over_250_of_1000_ful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Lsj.png)

Can you please help me understand what that plot is and how we remove it from tensorboard.

I also want to know how we can show the "training accuracy" plot for each steps like "Loss".

Thank you

Comment: I have the same two questions.